# C++ main vs C main

Tags: c++, c, standards, program-entry-point

I am reading a document about C++ vs C. The document says C++ is tightly written when compared to C. One instance is, C allows `main()` function type to be void. On the other hand C++ does not allow that and he gave the below statement from the standard.

In the C++ Standard:

> It shall have a return type of int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> ```
> int main() { /* … */ }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* … */ }
> ```

The C standard says the same but has an additional statement.

> If the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified

which indicates that allowing forms that do not return int is intentional.

When you have the statement "type can be implementation-defined" are you not allowing room for the C++ compiler implementation community to allow void as a type?

Comment: Main in C must always return int

Comment: What document are you reading, exactly? Standard C isn't any less "tightly written" than standard C++.

Comment: iso/iec 9899:1999 5.1.2.2.1 & 5.1.2.2.3 for C. iso/iec 14882:1998 for cpp.

Comment: @awoodland: See Kerrek's answer...

Comment: @awoodland, gcc compiler did not complain for the statement void main(void). on the other g++ for the statement void main (void), error:: main must return an int.

Comment: @ram, when you're testing `gcc` for standards-compliance, always use `-pedantic-errors`.  gcc 4.6.2 will then say, "error: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both C and C++ require that any implementation of the language must support the forms `int main(void)` and `int main(int, char**)`. However, the standards also say that additional forms may be supported by the implementation, and thus a program that uses one of those other forms is not automatically *invalid* -- rather, it is a valid program that only happens to be supported on certain platforms.

The only difference between C and C++ in that regard is *which* alternative forms of `main` are permitted. In C++, all forms must return `int`, so only the arguments are allowed to vary, and moreover, if the first two arguments of *any* form are `int, char**`, they *should* have the usual meaning.

C is a little more liberal, as it allows *any* alternative form of `main`. Thus a program  with `void main(char, double)` is a valid C program that requires the implementation to support this signature, while it would unconditionally be ill-formed C++. On the other hand, `int main(int, char**, char**)` is a permissible signature for both C and C++, also requiring implementation support, and C++ would expect the first two arguments to have the usual meaning.

Comment: @ kerrek SB, is it now safe to assume that, c++ has the ability to supports all variants of main under the condition that main() must always return a value and its type has to be 'int'. There are no such constrictions for main() in 'c'.

Comment: @ram: Don't get this the wrong way: C++ is an abstract language standard. It doesn't "have abilities" of any sort. It's just a formal document. What it says is that your code is well-formed if it has any of the permitted forms of `main`, but that you can only expect any given compiler to compile it if it has one of the two standard forms. Otherwise your compiler has to support your form explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

**C++**

> It shall have a return type of int, but otherwise its type is
>   implementation-defined.

That means that the return type **must** be int, but that the parameters to main **can** be implementation defined. So there is scope for implementation specific parameters to main, but no scope for variation from an int return type.

**C**

C is more permissive over the allowable return types of main. It does allow return types other than int.

Comment: you mean command line arguments? could you please elaborate a bit more on what you actually mean? tq.

Comment: The formal parameters to the main function can be implementation defined. But not the return value type. That must be int.